# Loop that generates all possible linear models and replaces the dependent variable name with a value from a list

Tags: r, loops, foreach, linear-regression

So I want to test all possible linear regression models obtainable with 1 to 5 independent variables and one of the 18 dependent variables.
I have the code working for generating all the linear regression models with the 1st dependent variable and the 5 independent ones, but I am unsure how to run this code for each of the 18 dependent variables I want to check for.

`GClist <- data.frame(GC1, GC2, GC3, GC4, GC5, GC6, GC7, GC8, GC9, GC10, GC11, GC12, GC13, GC14, GC15, GC16, GC17, GC18)`

So far, I made a list of the 18 DVs, I also tried to loop using a foreach loop and then trying to parse a list containing the 18 DV names.

I tried to use:

```
for(value in GClist)
{
the code below
}
// but then I did not manage to make it work and include the "value" in the code

// I also tried to use foreach, but I using df[j] and having df containing all my 18 dependent variables did not seem to work.


foreach (j=1:18) %do% {the code below }
```

Anyway, the code that works is this:

````
df1 <- data.frame(GC1, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5)
library(foreach)

#create the linear models list 

xcomb <- foreach(i=1:5, .combine=c) %do% {combn(names(df1)[-1], i, simplify=FALSE) }
formlist <- lapply(xcomb, function(l) formula(paste(names(df1), paste(l, collapse="+"), sep="~")))```

 # get the p value for each model
models.p <- sapply(formlist, function (i)  {
  f <- summary(lm(i))$fstatistic
  p <- pf(f[1],f[2],f[3],lower.tail=F)
  attributes(p) <- NULL
  return(p)
})
# R squared for each model
models.r.sq <- sapply(formlist, function(i) summary(lm(i))$r.squared)
# adjusted R squared for each model
models.adj.r.sq <- sapply(formlist, function(i) summary(lm(i))$adj.r.squared)
# MSEp squared for each model
models.MSEp <- sapply(formlist, function(i) anova(lm(i))['Mean Sq']['Residuals',])

# Full model MSE for each linear model
MSE <- anova(lm(formlist[[length(formlist)]]))['Mean Sq']['Residuals',]

# Mallow's Cp - skipped for now 

df.model.eval <- data.frame(model=as.character(formlist), pF=models.p,
                            r.sq=models.r.sq, adj.r.sq=models.adj.r.sq, MSEp=models.MSEp)
````

How can I run this code for each of the 18 dependent variables, so that I can gather all the information in df.model.eval? Right now I have everything I need to know about the models that use GC1 as the dependent variable. My goal is to see all the models (from GC1 to GC18) and highlight all that have statistical significance and those that don't.

Comment: "highlight all that have statistical significance and those that don't" I hope you at least adjust the p-values if you must do this at all. It looks like you are engaging in [data dredging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dredging).

Comment: @Roland Indeed, it might seem like that. I did however, create my hypothesis in advance and will definitely research further into adjusting my p-values, so that I avoid presenting irrelevant data. To give you some context, I am testing if the Big Five Personality domains are predictors of the acceptance of certain (18) gift categories.
Adjusted R squared is also important for me and also running ANOVA on multiple models, so that I establish the predicting power of each model, and not just statistical significance.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it, by creating a dataframe with possible DVs;

`GC <- data.frame(GC1, GC2, GC3, GC4, GC5, GC6, GC7, GC8, GC9, GC10, GC11, GC12, GC13, GC14, GC15, GC16, GC17, GC18)`

Then, using George Dontas' code found at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/6862, I prepare my first dataframe to generate linear regression models.

```
library(foreach)

finallist <- list()
xcomb <- foreach(i=1:5, .combine=c) %do% {combn(names(df1)[-1], i, simplify=FALSE) }
```

I am replacing the first element of my dataframe here:

```
for(j in c(names(GC)))
{
  names(df1)[1] <- j #switch DVs
  #George's code to create a list with all the possible combinations of the DV and the IVs
  formlist <- lapply(xcomb, function(l) formula(paste(names(df1), paste(l, collapse="+"), sep="~"))) 
  #append the list of linear regression models for each DV to the main list
  finallist <- append(finalist, formlist)
}
```

I now have a list of all the linear regression models, which I can then use to assess and interpret relevant statistical indices, with the
as.character(finallist)

My final code is:

```
df1 <- data.frame(GC1, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5)
library(foreach)
library(rlist)
finallist <- list()
xcomb <- foreach(i=1:5, .combine=c) %do% {combn(names(df1)[-1], i, simplify=FALSE) }

#iterate through DV names
for(j in c(names(GC)))
{
  names(df1)[1] <- j #switch DVs (I know 1st step replaces same DV name)
  #create a list with all the possible combinations of the DV and the IVs
  formlist <- lapply(xcomb, function(l) formula(paste(names(df1), paste(l, collapse="+"), sep="~"))) 
  #append the list of linear regression models for each DV to the main list
  finallist <- append(finalist, formlist)
}

# get the p value for each model
models.p <- sapply(formlist, function (i)  {
  f <- summary(lm(i))$fstatistic
  p <- pf(f[1],f[2],f[3],lower.tail=F)
  attributes(p) <- NULL
  return(p)
})
# R squared for each model
models.r.sq <- sapply(finallist, function(i) summary(lm(i))$r.squared)
# adjusted R squared for each model
models.adj.r.sq <- sapply(finallist, function(i) summary(lm(i))$adj.r.squared)
# MSEp squared for each model
models.MSEp <- sapply(finallist, function(i) anova(lm(i))['Mean Sq']['Residuals',])

# Full model MSE for each linear model
MSE <- anova(lm(finallist[[length(finallist)]]))['Mean Sq']['Residuals',]

# Mallow's Cp - skipped for now 

df.model.eval <- data.frame(model=as.character(finallist), pF=models.p,
                            r.sq=models.r.sq, adj.r.sq=models.adj.r.sq, MSEp=models.MSEp)
```